# How can I identify the Input Formats in MapReduce Program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, mapr

I just started learning Hadoop and there are various formats of input types. I have few programs to study and my main question is how can I identify if the input format is TextInputFormat or KeyValueTextInputFormat or any other.
Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to *identify* which `InputFormat` is being used by the MapReduce program.

`InputFormat` is something that you can specify in your program explicitly and the MapReduce job will use that.

If you don't specify anything, it uses the default which is [`TextInputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html) which extends `FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Key>`. That's why in a simple wordcount program, you would often see the `Mapper` class defined as :

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Key, Text, IntWritable> {
    //...
}
```

You can specify the InputFormat to use in the `JobConf` object :

```
JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), MyJob.class);

job.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Link to: [InputFormat.class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) for further reading.